# How do i get password value in data connection using regex

Tags: regex

I need to grab the value of password from db connection string using regex.

This is my current regex `.*;(?i)Password=([^;]*)`. 
This works only if there is not any `;` character in password.

```
add key="myKey" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test-user;Password=pA&-pass; unicode=True"
```

But it fails if there is `;` character in password

```
add key="myKey" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test-user;Password=pass&amp;gt;; unicode=True"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

There will always be ways for your code to break since someone can create a password such as `;Password=` such that your string is actually `;Password=;Password=;`.

Assuming that is not possible (and also assuming it's not possible for someone to use similar variations such as portions of the password being in the following format `;s=` where `s` is any word or space character), this should work for you.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DXPxDi/3)

```
(?<=;Password=)(?:(?!;[\w ]+=).)*
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
add key="myKey" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test-user;Password=pA&-pass; unicode=True"
add key="myKey" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test-user;Password=pass&gt;; unicode=True"
```

#### Output

```
pA&-pass
pass&gt;
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=;Password=)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `;Password` literally
- `(?:(?!;[\w ]+=).)*` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character, but ensuring it doesn't match `;`, followed by any word or space characters, followed by `=`

Comment: Nice one, even matches if the password is the last property of the connection string.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will let you know if this work. ;Password=;Password=; There is the possibility for it to be happened.

Comment: @istudent If you want everything preceding `;Password=` (and including it) you can use `.*;Password=` instead of `(?<=;Password=)`. You may also want to place the entire tempered greedy token inside a capture groups such that your pattern is `.*;Password=((?:(?!;[\w ]+=).)*)`